# Why const pair isn't boost is_pair?

Tags: c++, boost

As I can see on boost [is_pair implementation](https://github.com/boostorg/odeint/blob/develop/include/boost/numeric/odeint/util/is_pair.hpp) a const pair (or volatile pair) is not a pair.
There is a reason for that?

Comment: Traits typically only operate on unqualified types. It's just a convention.

Answer (score 2):

It is because of the way it is implemented. In order to make it work for `const std::pair` you'll have to provide the corresponding specialization:

```
// DO NOT DO THIS IN REAL CODE - EXAMPLE ONLY
template<class T1 , class T2>
struct is_pair<const std::pair<T1 , T2>>  : public std::true_type {};
```

And you'll have to provide the same overload for rvalue, lvalue, etc. So the usual solution is to provide the type without any qualifiers. There is an `std::decay` for this. Or since C++20 you can use `std::remove_cvref`.

> `std::decay` applies lvalue-to-rvalue, array-to-pointer, and
> function-to-pointer implicit conversions to the type T, removes
> cv-qualifiers, and defines the resulting type as the member typedef
> type.

And of course any problem with templates in C++ can be solved with introduction of another template. You can provide your own templated struct `is_pair_d`. This is std-based solution, but can be used with `boost` as well.

```
#include <utility>
#include <type_traits>

template< class T >
struct is_pair : std::false_type {};

template< class T1 , class T2 >
struct is_pair< std::pair< T1 , T2 > > : std::true_type {};

template< class T >
struct is_pair_d : is_pair<typename std::decay<T>::type> {};

// a helper function for value
template<class T>
inline constexpr bool is_pair_d_v = is_pair_d<T>::value;

int main()
{
    std::pair<int,int> p1;
    const std::pair<int,int> p2;
    auto &&p2_r = p2;
    auto &p2_l = p2;

    static_assert(is_pair<decltype(p1)>::value);
    static_assert(!is_pair<decltype(p2)>::value);
    static_assert(is_pair<std::decay_t<decltype(p2)>>::value); // C++11
    static_assert(is_pair<std::remove_cvref_t<decltype(p2_r)>>::value); // C++20

    static_assert(is_pair_d_v<decltype(p1)>);
    static_assert(is_pair_d_v<decltype(p2)>);
    static_assert(is_pair_d_v<decltype(p2_r)>);
    static_assert(is_pair_d_v<decltype(p2_l)>);

    return 0;
}
```

There is a [coliru link](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8959562ce2457018) kindly provided by @Scheff. And [godbolt link](https://godbolt.org/z/vq3srz). You can play with the code there.